# iOS - Untint UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, tint

I know how to tint an `UIImage`:

```
UIImage* originalImage = curiv.image;
UIImage* imageForRendering = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
curiv.image = imageForRendering;
curiv.tintColor = [UIColor RedColor];
```

But how to untint to original `UIImage`?

Comment: You can save the `tintcolor` of `UIImage`, just before tinting it with red color,  now id you want to untint it, then set the previously saved tintcolor. If this is not the case, then provide more code for details.

Comment: @ViralSavaj How to save `tintColor` of `UIImage`? That is about the code I have for `tintColor`.

Comment: Please take look at my answer,

Comment: Since the default `tintColor` of a `UIImageView` is `nil` you could just set it to `nil` again to revert into its original state...

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this way

```
UIImage* originalImage = curiv.image;
UIImage* imageForRendering = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
curiv.image = imageForRendering;
UIColor *prevTintColor = curiv.tintColor;
//set new Tint color as Red
curiv.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];


//Now if you want to set back previous color
curiv.tintColor=prevTintColor;
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: It works but not really solve my problem. Because the `UIImages` are all dynamic and I might have several to untint. Anyway, thanks for the solution.

Comment: There is no tintColor property in a WKInterfaceImage or UIImage object. The developer docs on developer.apple.com don't expose any methods called "tintColor", but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @simonzhu You are halfly right, there is no`tintColor` for 'UIImage', but We have get and set `tintColor` for `UIImageView`, in above Q&A `curiv` is an object of `UIImageView`. So we can set `tintColor` for that. You can refer this from Apple Developer Doc.